# cloudprint anonymous register: "Unable to get the authorization code"

Tags: google-cloud-print

Totally stuck & lost in Google CloudPrint documentation & python code. I am writing a 'proxy' service connector to interface between printers and Google CloudPrint service. It appears that I am able successfully to first register the printer anonymously (from the proxy), the user can claim it via the provided link. BUT the printer does NOT appear in the user's GCP managed printer list. AND, on the proxy side, I am unable to get the authorization code, with the response returning that as an error. Before the user claims the printer, however, the poll request does return "Token not registered yet." And after the token has expired or been used, it returns: "Unknown, used or expired token." So why won't it return the authorization code and why won't the printer show up in the managed printer list? What is missing from the request?

Here is the request & response for the register phase:

```
post https://www.google.com/cloudprint/register
X-CloudPrint-Proxy: "my proxy"
Content-Type: "multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------RubyMultipartPost"
Content-Length: "25074"
Status: 200
response: Content-Type: "text/plain"
Set-Cookie: "NID=67=Vr4laL1-skwakQVraGiu-l7i_dONBY5Szu7RAsCiHV5hSRmI8XDUbRQf4l1K7ct5ZCJzPjuZB97wJdvEYUXSGUpsrCnhVZRWuyq-CyQ0KSCvDegdUNz0VgDnH1LPwJBI;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Sun, 30-Mar-2014 07:42:54 GMT;HttpOnly"
{"success"=>true, "polling_url"=>"https://www.google.com/cloudprint/getauthcode?printerid=a274981a-e4e7-ea3c-3ea1-e77adb84b5b4&oauth_client_id=", "invite_page_url"=>"https://www.google.com/cloudprint/regtokenpage?t=q2c5n&dpi=300&pagesize=215900,279400", "complete_invite_url"=>"http://goo.gl/printer/0jg9", "automated_invite_url"=>"https://www.google.com/cloudprint/confirm?token=q2c5n", "oauth_scope"=>"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudprint", "token_duration"=>"899", "request"=>{"time"=>"0", "params"=>{"default_display_name"=>["HP-LaserJet-1020test"], "proxy"=>["my proxy"], "auth_client_id"=>["AIzaSyDnm....PeW0lu9Y"], "printer"=>["HP-LaserJet-1020test"]}}, "registration_token"=>"q2c5n" ...
```

Here is the poll request & response for the authorization code:

```
post https://www.google.com/cloudprint/getauthcode?printerid=a274981a-e4e7-ea3c-3ea1-e77adb84b5b4&oauth_client_id=AIzaSyD.....Mpe2PByWPeW0lu9Y
X-CloudPrint-Proxy: "my proxy"
Cookie: "NID=67=Vr4laL1-skwakQVraGiu-l7i_dONBY5Szu7RAsCiHV5hSRmI8XDUbRQf4l1K7ct5ZCJzPjuZB97wJdvEYUXSGUpsrCnhVZRWuyq-CyQ0KSCvDegdUNz0VgDnH1LPwJBI"
Status: 200
response: Content-Type: "text/plain"

{"success"=>false, "message"=>"Unable to get the authorization code.", "request"=>{"time"=>"0", "params"=>{"oauth_client_id"=>["AIzaSyDnmcwkVP....WPeW0lu9Y"], "printerid"=>["a274981a-e4e7-ea3c-3ea1-e77adb84b5b4"]}}, "errorCode"=>505}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured things out. Repeated references in the documentation and code samples to "API key" confused me. the "client_id" parameter needs to be the same "Client ID" field from the Google API console and will be a string looking something like this: "
40nnnnnnnnn96.apps.googleusercontent.com" where nnnnn are various digits. The Google APIs console is at: [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/) . Do NOT use the API key for browser apps (that's what I was doing wrong).

Once you've claimed the authorization_code, then the printer will show up in the users managed printers list.

The full and correct polling query will look similar to the following (confidential information has been blurred with xxxxxx's and nnnnnnn's)

post https://www.google.com/cloudprint/getauthcode?printerid=c9xxxxcc-bxxx2-0xx5-9xxx-9cxxxxxxxxxde&oauth_client_id=40nnnnnnnn96.apps.googleusercontent.com